# Chunk processing of Files in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to implement File processing using the FlatFileItemReader class.What I would like to accomplish is to read 100 lines in a file separately in a partition.I was trying to set the "from" and "to" using the ExecutionContext.But I see that the FlatFileItemReader does not have the parameterValues() for the values to be read.The partitioner class looks like this:

```
@Override  public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) 
    {    
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
        File dir = new File(inboundDir); 

        int range = 1;
        int fromId = 1;
        int toId = range;


        if (dir.isDirectory())
        {       File[] files = dir.listFiles();   

            for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {

                ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext(); 

                context.putInt("fromId", fromId);
                context.putInt("toId", toId);

                                context.putString("name", "Thread" + i);
                partitionMap.put("partition" + i, context);

                fromId = toId + 1;
                toId += range;

        }
        }
        return partitionMap;  
    }
```

The input reader that I have defined in the spring context file is :

```
<bean name="inventoryLoadReader" scope="step"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:sample01.txt" />
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="inventoryLineMapper" />
        <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />

        <property name="parameterValues">
            <map>
                <entry key="fromId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}" />
                <entry key="toId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}" />
            </map>
        </property>


    </bean>.
```

Do I have to write a customized reader?Also,Do I need to set the "from" and "to" values into the executionContext for this to work.Or is there a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: I guess my question is if I have 1000 records in my file and my grid size mentioned is 10,is that sufficient to ensure that each partition processes 100 records.In my partitioner class,I have code that adds values to the Execution Context for each thread.